# Ubuntu 22.04.2 takes too long to boot under Linux 5.19.0-46-generic from the official repositories

Tags: boot, nvidia, 22.04, amd-ryzen, integrated

I have a fresh Ubuntu install from yesterday. To have WiFi working, I installed lwfinger's rtw88 kernel modules with dkms.
I tried installing more recent Kernels and the result was complete freeze at startup.
I own a Ryzen 5 7600 processor with a Radeon RDMA 2 iGPU and a Asus PRIME B650M-A II CSM Board, with a RTX3050 Graphics card, with the Privative NVidia 525.125.06  Driver from the official Ubuntu Repositories.
Computer freezes at boot showing this message:

```
hub 8-0:1.0: config failed, hub doesn't have any ports! (err -19)
```

I tried with Linux 6.3.13 and 6.4.4 from de Kernel PPA and with OEM version for kernel 6.1 from the Ubuntu's official repository.
I'm tired of waiting my PC to boot. It seems it's not a Kernel issue since I tested a lot of kernels. Please help me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Sorry that you are encountering problems. It's unclear if you are seeking help with freezes, or with lengthy boot times. AskUbuntu uses a question/Answer format, not threaded discussion. "*Please help me*" is not an answerable question; it's the start of a discussion (which we don't do here). See https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask for some good advice on how to edit your question to attract useful answers.

Comment: I'll be more clear. Right now I've installed Ubuntu 23.04. It works well.
I think it was a Kernel issue... Upgrading to the next 6.2 Kernel fixed it.
Although, I think 6.2 kernel should be supported by LTS version. Right now, people buy AMD Ryzen 7000 processors and they're unsupported by Ubuntu :\
With LTS installed it booted in almost 5 minutes. With more recent kernels and LTS it didn't boot at all!
That was the problem.

Comment: Please edit your question instead of commenting upon your own question.